# Django - CheckboxSelectMultiple without list?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to use form's `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget but I I'd like to change the way it is outputted. Is there a way to remove or change the `<li>` to something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [implementation of CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L743-760) is hard-coded to use a `<ul><li></li></ul>` form. The only way to change it would be to subclass the object and override the `render` method.